# php delete where it matches the word "last"

Tags: php, regex

I have some text like `$text="aaaa Last name:aaa city:aaaa email:ddd"`
I want the output as `$output="aaaa"`.
In simple words strip off everything starting from word "Last".
I am not getting hpw to do this.

Comment: is $text always in the same order separated by a single space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$parts = explode( ' Last', $text );
$output = $parts[0];
```

Or:

```
$output = substr( $text, 0, strpos( $text, ' Last'  ) );
```

(The latter works only if you're sure that the word "Last" is there.)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Find the position of the string
$pos = strpos($text, 'Last');
// Strip off the text after the position, or return whole string if not found
$result = ($pos !== FALSE) ? trim(substr($text, 0, $pos)) : $text;
```

The advantage of this over @Juhana's (perfectly acceptable) `explode()` approach is that this can easily be made case-insensitive with the use of `stripos()`. I have thrown a `trim()` in there as I suspect this is likely to be what you want, but YMMV.

[See it working](http://codepad.org/N5tc8hPp)

Answer (score 1):

What @juhana said works great.. except in  the event where aaaa = Last IE: `Last Last name: aaa`

**To combat this:**

i would suggest putting a semi-colon between each section.

`$text = "aaaa;LastName:aaa;city:aaaa;email:ddd"`

then using split or explode like so:

```
<?php
$text = split(';', $text);
$save = $text[0];
?>
```

Comment: extra jobs ! he did not need to add a blank to string the currect answer is for Juhana

Comment: My answer is simply another approach at the problem. I noted that juhana is the correct answer.